# Google translate is creating a footer whitespace. How I can remove with css?

Tags: css, whitespace, google-translate

I want really ask for help here about this issue.

I have a Wordpress Webisite address: http://www.marcoborla.it
if you see on the right bar there are Google translate this cause to me to have white space created by Google at the footer.

If I remove google translate all is correct, footer end where footer is.

I need a CSS or a solution for remove the big white space hole after the footer.
Do you know how I can fix this issue?

1. Navigate into my website
2. Go to footer and you can see white space.

Screen:
https://s5.postimg.org/h9o8hjnxz/image.png

Thank you anyone will help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the CSS solution that works:

```
.goog-te-spinner-pos + div {
height: auto !important;
}
```

Thanks to an user that helped me on Wordpress Forum.

Answer (score 0):

While inspecting your code, found the following code

```
<div style="position: absolute;z-index: -10000;top: 0px;left: 0px;right: 0px;/* height: 3955px; */"></div>
```

Here you have commented out the height but it seems like active on DOM. Removing the height solved your issue. Try to remove the height and fix the css issue.

Hope it helps.. :)